# Draw parallel curve line svg using a single SVG-path?

Tags: svg

[Prallel lines use two srokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhwjB.jpg)

Initially I drew 2 parallel lines with 2 different strokes an no problem at all.

But when I use only one stroke, the problem is that when it is drawn in the opposite direction the curvature is changed (the red and the blue lines do not overlap).

[Prallel lines use only one sroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrdgO.jpg)

So how to draw two parallel lines using only a single stroke?

Comment: Please post code as text and not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reverse the second path you need to:

Move to or line to the last point.

Use the second control point as the first control point.

Use the first control point as the second control point.

End the curve where you had the move to command.

```css
svg{border:solid; background:white;}

path{stroke:red;fill:none;}
.b{stroke:rgba(200,200,0,.25);stroke-width:10 }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 350 400">
  <g>
  <path d="M100,350 C100,350 100,50 250,50" />
  <path d="M120,350 C120,350 120,70 250,70" />
  
  <path class="b" 
        d="M100,350 C100,350 100,50 250,50 
           M250,70 C120,70 120,350 120,350" />
  </g>
</svg>
```